# overwrite all values of a sparse matrix in rcpp armadillo

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, eigen, rcpp, armadillo

I'm getting started with rcpp and am not sure how to convert a portion of my code to c++

My process uses sparse matrices in which the elements are all operated on as vectors then inserted back into a sparse matrix. In R I can use

```
sparse_mat@x <- new_entries
```

Where `sparse_mat` is a dsCMatrix (columns based symmetric matrix) and `new_entries` is a vector of values ordered so as to match the matrix they are being inserted into.

Is such an overwriting process possible using rcpp Armadillo or Eigen? I want to be able to do it this way as then the rest of the operations are simply vector manipulation which is much faster.

What I have tried to do so far is the following. The function is supposed to replace all the values in the sparse matrix with a vector (this is just for testing not the real function)

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::sp_mat sqrt2_(arma::sp_mat X, Rcpp::NumericVector a) {

// In order to access the internal arrays of the SpMat class
//X.sync();

std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), arma::access::rwp(X.values));

return sqrt(X);
}
```

But it produces and error "elf_dynamic_array_reader" and "tag not found".

I am using the `.sync` method becuase it is suggested [here](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/as-and-wrap-for-sparse-matrices/) as a way to access the matrix internals.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the sparse matrix examples at the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/) (by adding 'sparse' to the site-local search bar) ?